# Angular - Wait till the method returns the response

Tags: angular

I know there might be some related answer on my question, but I couldn't find the appropriate answer and am new to Angular.

I have a method which will assign some static value to the array and it will for another method to get some dynamic value from API, and again it will update some static values to the array.

appComponent

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: './home.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./home.component.scss']
})
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {

  apiServer: string = 'https://itunes.apple.com/search';
  result: string[] = [];

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.test();
  }

  test() {
    this.result.push('test1');
    this.testing('iphone');
    this.result.push('test2');
  }

  testing(q: string) {
    let promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      let url = `${this.apiServer}?term=${q}&media=music&limit=20`;
      this.http.get(url).toPromise().then(
        (res: any) => {
          console.log('res');
          res.results.map((item: any) => {
            console.log(item);
            this.result.push(item.kind);
          });
          console.log(this.result);
          resolve(res);
        },
        err => {
          console.log(err);
          reject(err);
        }
      )
    });
    return promise;
  }
}
```

appComponent.html

`<div *ngFor="let a of result">{{a}}</div>`

Output should be

```
test1
...
...
...
...
...
test2
```

I have tried with aysnc and await but am not sure how to use that in order to get the result.

But I have got

```
test1
test2
...
...
...
```

Comment: what's the output in the console?

Comment: I have updated in the description. @deelde

Answer (score 1):

This is not an issue with Angular. You have used Promise in the wrong way. `this.result.push('test2')` should be written inside `.then()` of your `this.testing('iphone')` for the result that you want to get. Or you can write it inside `testing` function itself as `promise.then(data=>//here)`.

```
test() {
    this.result.push('test1');
    this.testing('iphone').then((results)=>{
    results.map((item: any) => {
       this.result.push(item.kind);
    });
    this.result.push('test2');
});
  }

  testing(q: string) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      let url = `${this.apiServer}?term=${q}&media=music&limit=20`;
      this.http.get(url).then(res=>res.json()).then((res: any) => {
          resolve(res.results);
        },
        err => {
          console.log(err);
          reject(err);
        }
      )
    });
  }
```